# PHP 5.2 or 5.3 for Drupal 6.22?

Tags: 6

I have noticed that PHP 5.2 is [officially](http://drupal.org/requirements) recommended for Drupal 5 and 6. But as the 'System Requirement' page needs update, I am wondering what would be the anticipated problems using Drupal 5.3.

I have been using PHP 5.3.2 + FPM on a Drupal 6.22 site, and have some JavaScript issues with the Voting UP/Down and Poll modules. Is it possible that I can resolve these by downgrading PHP to 5.2?

Answer (score 6):

Drupal 6.22 is compatible with PHP 5.3, but some contributed modules may not support 5.3. That said, I have been developing D6 sites on 5.3 for more than a year without any problems.

Usually, the PHP version is not the cause of JS problems, so I would start to look for the solution elsewhere (Firebug?).

Comment: Thanks. What are the incompatible modules with php 5.3?

Comment: If php is erroring out or generating some warnings on a ajax callback, it may indeed be affecting ajax-heavy modules like vote up/down.

Comment: @Entendu How this Ajax-related errors can be resolved?

Comment: There isn't really a list of modules problematic with 5.3.  Watch the AJAX transfer w/ Firebug.  Often, you see a PHP message come back as the response instead of the JSON if it is a 5.2 vs 5.3 problem.